# raise Exception inside if condition in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
declare
      cnt number; 
begin
      select count(*)
      into cnt
       FROM employee;
       IF cnt = 0 THEN
               DELETE employee;
               COMMIT;
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN others THEN
               log_error_local(k_sub_module, l_step||' '||sqlerrm);
       raise;
       END IF;
    end
```

getting syntax error like below..
Error(188,13): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Comment: You count if there are any employees and if there are no employees then you delete all the employees; since at that point you know there are no employees then the `DELETE` appears to be pointless. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ideally your `log_error_local` procedure would capture `sqlerrm` itself, instead of requiring developers to concatenate it into every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your syntax issues, you can wrap the contents of the `IF .. THEN` statement in a `BEGIN`/`END` block:

```sql
DECLARE
  cnt number; 
BEGIN
  select count(*)
  into cnt
  FROM employee;
  
  IF cnt = 0 THEN
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM employee;
      COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        log_error_local(k_sub_module, l_step||' '||sqlerrm);
        raise;
    END;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

*Note: the `DELETE` statement is missing the `FROM` keyword and you do not appear to have declared the `k_sub_module` or `l_step` variables.*

or, since you are re-raising the exception and execution will be halted anyway, catch the exception outside the `IF` statement in the main block:

```sql
DECLARE
  cnt number; 
BEGIN
  select count(*)
  into cnt
  FROM employee;
  
  IF cnt = 0 THEN
    DELETE FROM employee;
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    log_error_local(k_sub_module, l_step||' '||sqlerrm);
    raise;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f8ea2e03098ed6a9ae2e459b82b72678)*